# What is the ideal political period for liberal conservatives?

Tags: conservatism, liberalism

What is the ideal political period in the eyes of liberal conservatives?

Liberal conservatism is "a political ideology combining conservative policies with liberal stances, especially on economic issues but also on social and ethical matters" (Wikipedia).

It is represented by authors such as Edmund Burke, Alexis de Tocqueville, Roger Scruton, and Friedrich Hayek.

Not very astonishingly, they are famously opposed to the French revolution.

But more generally, they are very critical of the whole Enlightenment intellectual and political period.

So what is, in the eyes of the liberal conservatives the historical period which best embodies their ideals?

In other words, are there so historical periods that they often cite or refer to as exemplifying their ideas?

Is it the “classical republics” of Ancient Greece city states, Ancient Rome Republic, or the republic of Renaissance Florence?

Comment: Questions about *historical periods" generally belong on [History SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/) unless they relate to contemporary politics. Where, in this question,  is that connection?

Comment: @RickSmith I disagree because by "historical period" I refer to a kind of political philosophy concretely inacted during a certain period of time. So still talking about politics, and not history

Comment: You are asking about political history and so [History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/) would be the right place for this question. But I've noticed that they often send political question back to us. :) Unfortunately, political history questions tend to get ignored here and often don't get good answers (in my opinion). Your question is likely to get better answers in History. Right now I will vote to not close your question, and leave the decision to you.

Comment: @sfxedit I don't think my question is related to political history. I edited my question to make it clearer

Comment: Amusingly enough, how about Putinism?

Comment: While this is not unsalvageable, this question needs an edit to make it more clear.  As it is currently written, it reads more like an invitation for speculation.  It probably needs   "[tag:ideology]" tag, too.

Answer (score 5):

I think if you read [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_conservatism) a bit further, you will see that you need to define which *kind* of liberal conservative you mean, starting with "European" versus "American", and going on from there.

More generally, the term itself seems to be an oxymoron. The original idea of "[conservatism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservatism)" is the preservation of traditional institutions, customs and values. However in many (if not all) countries those traditional institutions, customs and values are often highly illiberal. Traditional institutions generally include a religious denomination that seeks to exclude all others, and values such as patriarchy, homophobia and xenophobia. All of this is directly opposed to liberal values of tolerance, individual freedom, inclusivity and multiculturalism.

So perhaps the best answer is "thirty years ago, and always has been". Most people who might self-identify as liberal conservatives will approve of changes which have been around for most of their lives but still reflexively oppose innovations.

This [Douglas Adams quote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Douglas_Adams) sums the attitude up quite nicely:

> I've come up with a set of rules that describe our reactions to technologies:
>
> 1. Anything that is in the world when you’re born is normal and ordinary and is just a natural part of the way the world works.
> 2. Anything that's invented between when you’re fifteen and thirty-five is new and exciting and revolutionary and you can probably get a career in it.
> 3. Anything invented after you're thirty-five is against the natural order of things.

Adams was talking about technology, but the pattern applies to social innovations too.

Answer (score 4):

Allow me to point out that this post cites people who are nearly 300 years apart in time, which confounds things. For example, Hayek and Scruton (if pressed) might point to the late 19th or early 20th centuries (pre-New-Deal for Hayek, height of the British Colonial Empire for Scruton), but Burke and de Tocqueville couldn't do the same, since they were, you know… long dead by then.

But be that as it may, Liberal Conservatism doesn't so much point to a specific, factual period of time as to an aesthetic and cultural ideal that is *projected backwards* through time. Essentially, Liberal Conservatism pines for the way the world *would have been* had we not discarded our cultural and aesthetic ideals in a headlong rush for progress. None of these people would say that any particular time-frame was perfect. Instead, they would say that the values inherent some previous time contained the seeds of the good society which had not yet come to fruition, seeds that might be destroyed by rampant, ill-considered advancement. They are Liberal because they believe in the rights and liberties of individuals, and conservative because they believe the path to achieving the rights and liberties was written in older, more stable and traditional worldviews.

It's important not to confuse this kind of Liberal Conservatism with the reactionary mythological absolutism of the various forms of Nationalism. Liberal Conservatives want to recover and preserve important values moving forward; nationalists want to eradicate progress and revert to a (largely imaginary) better time.